# Return the value of the whole array

Tags: arrays, return-value

This is my code that fetches the data from the database

```
public string showSkeds(string id)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("showSkeds", con);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = id;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    dt = hlp.resultHelper(cmd);
    int count = dt.Rows.Count;
    List<string> value = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)//rows
    {
        value.Add(dt.Rows[i][0].ToString() + "|" + dt.Rows[i][1].ToString());
    }
    string[] result = value.ToArray();

    return **result**;
}
```

and obviously the RESULT has an error because it cannot convert string[] to string. How can I return the values into plain text? Is it possible or is there a correct to return array values?

Comment: Why can you not have the method itself declared as returning a string array, ala `public string[]...`?

Comment: I really need that (string id) there, How can I incorporate that into my code?

Comment: `Arrays.toString(result)` will be the textual representation of the array (with square brackets and comma between elements).  Is this what you want or do you want to concat all content?  For that `String.join(" ", result)`

Comment: `string id` is the parameter you sent INTO the function, whereas `public string[] showSkeds...` would RETURN a string array.  What do you need **returned** is a better question?

Comment: I need to return the whole data of array that is being read. @gravity

Comment: I will provide the answer below, but please ensure your assignment (where you call `showSkeds`) is also accepting of a type of `string[]` as well - that is not in the above snippet.

Comment: okay sir thank you very much @gravity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per your clarifications in the comments, it looks like you would simply need to adjust the return type in the declaration of the function itself (look closely at the first line):

```
public string[] showSkeds(string id)
{
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("showSkeds", con);
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = id;
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  dt = hlp.resultHelper(cmd);
  int count = dt.Rows.Count;
  List<string> value = new List<string>();
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)//rows
  {
    value.Add(dt.Rows[i][0].ToString() + "|" + dt.Rows[i][1].ToString());
  }
  string[] result = value.ToArray();

  return result;
}
```

Since `result` is a type of `string[]`, the very first line (`public string[]..`) should also be of type `string[]` as well.

The type after `public`, `private`, is declaring the data type to be returned by the function, and expected to match the `return` line, where ever that may be.

Comment: thank you sir. little adjustment but I hope this can help others as well who will have a hard time using arrays.